# Filtering nested array using multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have an array like this

```
const treeObj = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Section One',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Section One Item One' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Section One Item Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Section One Item Three' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Section Two',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Section Three X',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Section Four X',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Section Three X',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Section Four X',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I need to write a search functionality that searches the array with an input. **I need to check whether string typed is matching each the outer name or any of the name inside items in each section.**

Like: `str === treeObj[0].name or str in any one of treeObj .items[].name`

I need the output in same structure. I'm familiar with filter. But i cant find the right way to do this, checking both section name and item names.

**Search the array with a string whether it matches eahc section naem or any one of names in items inside**

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

I tried this

```
 const searchStr = searchText.toLowerCase();
    filteredData = data.filter(obj => {
      if (obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr)) {
        return true;
      }
      if (obj.items.find(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr))) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
```

But it returns all items in a section. doesn't filter each section. I need to search to work for both section and items **(Try searching an item like: Section One Item One)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `find` and `filter`:

```
const str = "Section One Item One"

const filter = treeObj.filter(obj => {
  if(obj.name == str) {
    return true
  } else if(obj.items.find(item => item.name == str)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})

console.log(filter)
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/ZEQYGbN?editors=1011) with the code.

**EDIT**
I updated my original algorithm to better fit your needs:

```
const str = "Section One Item One"
let res = null

const filter = treeObj.some(obj => {
  if(obj.name == str) {
    res = obj;
    return true
  } 

  const item = obj.items.find(item => item.name == str);
  if(item) {
    res = {...obj, items: [item] }
    return true
  }
    return false;
});

console.log(res);
```

As suggested in the comments by [guyjob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6351322/guijob), I now use `some` to improve speed. When it finds a match, the search will be aborted. As some only returns `true` or `false`, I created a new `res` variable, which will contain the result of the search. In case of a match it will set `res` to the whole item if the name was found or filter all but the found element, when it was one of the subitems. I also updated the codepen.

Comment: `.some()` fits better in this case

Comment: I tried your code with some changes but didn't get the output as expected. Can you check the updated code in question

Comment: Do you only want the one matched item returned?

Comment: yeah the first section only. With all three items. i used includes instead of ===. the code is in the question

Comment: Just to be on the same page: When the name is matched, only `name: 'Section One'` should be returned. When an item is matched, only `{ id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' }` should be returned. Correct?

Comment: when u search for Section One, it should return only Section One and all 3 items, filtering should happen inside items as well. So if i search Section One Item One, it should return only first section with 1 item

Comment: @Gh05d i couldnt get it working . it says not able to assign boolean to any[]. I was able to find the answer. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @Wolverine, sounds like your Typescript interfered with my solution. I guess you would have to give filter a type of `any[] | boolean`. How did you solve your problem then?

Comment: @Gh05d I was able to finally get some solutions using all of your help. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it out by matching name:

```js
var treeObj = [ { id: 1, name: 'Section One', items: [ { id: 1, name: 'Section One Item One' }, { id: 2, name: 'Section One Item Two' }, { id: 3, name: 'Section One Item Three' }, { id: 3, name: 'Section One Item Four' } ], }, { id: 2, name: 'Section Two', items: [ { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' }, { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' }, { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' }, ], }, { id: 3, name: 'Section Three X', items: [ { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' }, { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' }, { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' }, ], }, { id: 4, name: 'Section Four X', items: [ { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' }, { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' }, { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' }, ], }, { id: 5, name: 'Section Three X', items: [ { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' }, { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' }, { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' }, ], }, { id: 6, name: 'Section Four X', items: [ { id: 1, name: 'Section Two Item One' }, { id: 2, name: 'Section Two Item Two' }, { id: 3, name: 'Section Two Item Three' }, ], }, ];
var strToSearch = 'Four';
var result = treeObj.filter(k=>k.name.includes(strToSearch) || k.items.some(s=>s.name.includes(strToSearch)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 filteredData = data
      .filter((element, index) => {
        const target = isSectionMatching.findIndex(item => item.id === element.id);
        isSectionMatching[target].match = element.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr);
        return (
          element.items.some(subElement => subElement.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr)) ||
          isSectionMatching[index].match
        );
      })
      .map((element, index) => {
        const target = isSectionMatching.findIndex(item => item.id === element.id);
        if (isSectionMatching[target].match) {
          return element;
        }
        return {
          ...element,
          items: element.items.filter(subElement => subElement.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr)),
        };
      });
  } else {
    filteredData = [...data];
  }
```

I had a custom requirement, so i was able to find a solution by combining all the answers i got to this question

Thanks to All contributors